# findAllbyId trazendo o mesmo resultado para toda a consulta

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Estou com um pequeno problema, minha consulta está retornando o mesmo resultado em todas as rows.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "UtilizadorPerfil.getByFilter", query = "SELECT u FROM UtilizadorPerfil u WHERE COD_UTILIZADOR = ?1 ")

public class UtilizadorPerfil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -232601683121391563L;
    
    @Id
    private Long COD_UTILIZADOR;    
    
    private Long COD_PERFIL;

getters setters...

@Repository
public interface UtilizadorPerfilRepository extends JpaRepository<UtilizadorPerfil, Long> {

    List<UtilizadorPerfil> getByFilter(Long cod);

}

Chamada

@Autowired
UtilizadorPerfilRepository utilPerfil;

List<UtilizadorPerfil> utilizadoresPerfis = utilPerfil.getByFilter(id);
```

Possiveis respostas para possiveis perguntas:

- Sim, no banco não existe nenhum resultado igual.
- Não existe relação com outra tabela, por mais que seja uma tabela composta, não posso mapear as outras tabelas, só preciso buscar esses resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema!

Era somente o @Id que estava na chave errada.